# % symbol in handlebar js

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I am new to handlebar js and I am building a ghost blog theme. In the below line of code, the % symbol is used to display the number of posts.

```
<div>
`{{plural meta.pagination.total empty='No posts' singular='% post' plural='See all % posts'}}
</div>
```

I didn't get how this is working, I haven't seen any documentation on what's the use of `%` symbol in handlebar js.

Can someone help me in understanding this better?

Answer (score 1):

The `%` symbol is the placeholder for the value, and will be replaced with the number returned from `meta.pagination.total`.